# How to show popup in flutter screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter so can anyone help me with this please.
I wish to add a popup in my flutter screen. Following is the image what I want in my flutter screen:

[image]

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: We call it in flutter; AlertDialog, you can type just that in google and you’ll find out more tutorials and examples about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Allow'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Block'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```